# Angular: why does Chrome need hash for root URL

Tags: angularjs

I see different behaviour between IE and Chrome for loading a root URL and I don't understand why.
My controller config is:

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
  title: "Home",
  controller: "mainController",
  controllerAs: "mainCtrl",
  templateUrl: "/templates/mainView.html"
}
```

I have a link in my navbar supposed to point to the root. If I include the hash in the URL, it works fine for Chrome. But if I just have a slash, it won't load the main controller/view. IE works whether I include it or not.

In other words, this works:

```
<a href="/#/">Home</a>
```

This doesn't:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Any ideas? I can get it working by including the hash, but I'd like to understand why I need to. Thanks for any hints.
Marcus

Comment: This is my first question on SO and I seem to have not got the code formatting working. The second a tag above was meant to have href="/". Equally, the controller config hasn't formatted correctly. Sorry. :-(

Comment: You can config angular run into HTML5 mode, which not include hash tag in url, see [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Comment: Thanks Marko for your help

Answer (score 0):

Angular works off the # tag if you don't have html5 mode set up. Let's say your application is here: `http://www.somedomain.com/myApp/` a `"/"` would bring you to here `http://www.somedomain.com/` while a `"/#/"` would bring you to here `http://www.somedomain.com/myApp/#/`

Comment: Thank you Mathew. I think I see the issue. If I just have '/' IE seems to transform it to '#/' so that the location becomes 'http://www.somedomain.com/#/'. That in turns makes the routing rule above work. Chrome seems not to do this. Strange.